# If cell is blank delete entire row

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel, I want to delete entire row if a cell is blank.
This should count for A17:A1000.
Running the script it returns the error:

> Run-time 1004 error
>   Method Range of object global failed

If I replace A17:A1000 with A it deletes some rows.

```
Sub DeleteBlanks()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim m As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    m = Range("A17:A1000" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For r = m To 1 Step -1
        If Range("A17:A1000" & r).Value = "" Or Range("A17:A1000" & r).Value = 0 Then
            Range("A17:A1000" & r).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next r
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue in your code is that it is counting wrong.
`"A17:A1000" & r` does not count the rows up but appends the number `r` to that string. So eg if `r = 500` it will result in `"A17:A1000500"` but not in `"A17:A1500"` as you might expected.

---

To delete all rows where column A has a blank cell you can use

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DeleteRowsWithBlankCellsInA()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A17:A1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

*This one deletes all blank lines at once and therefore is pretty fast. Also it doesn't need to disable `ScreenUpdating` because it is only one action.*

---

Or if blank and zero cells need to be deleted use

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DeleteRowsWithBlankOrZeroCellsInA()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'define which worksheet

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If ws.Cells(iRow, "A").Value = vbNullString Or ws.Cells(iRow, "A").Value = 0 Then
            ws.Rows(iRow).Delete
        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

*This one deletes line by line. Each delete action takes its time so it takes longer the more lines you delete. Also it might need to disable `ScreenUpdating` otherwise you see the line-by-line action.*

An alternative way is to collect all the rows you want to delete with `Union()` and then delete them at once.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DeleteRowsWithBlankOrZeroCellsInA()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  'define which worksheet

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim DeleteRange As Range

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = LastRow To 1 Step -1 'also forward looping is possible in this case: For iRow = 1 To LastRow
        If ws.Cells(iRow, "A").Value = vbNullString Or ws.Cells(iRow, "A").Value = 0 Then
            If DeleteRange Is Nothing Then
                Set DeleteRange = ws.Rows(iRow)
            Else
                Set DeleteRange = Union(DeleteRange, ws.Rows(iRow)) 'collect rows to delete
            End If
        End If
    Next iRow

    DeleteRange.Delete 'delete all at once
End Sub
```

*This is also pretty fast because you have again only one delete action. Also it doesn't need to disable `ScreenUpdating` because it is one action only.*

In this case it is also not necessary to loop backwards `Step -1`, because it just collects the rows in the loop and deletes at once (after the loop). So looping from `For iRow = 1 To LastRow` would also work.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors in your code.

1. First of all, your procedure should have it's scope declared.
   Presumably in your case `Private`
2. You are incorrectly defining your `Range()` Please look at [its definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel)
3. `Range.Value = 0` is not the same as `Range = ""` or better yet `IsEmpty(Range)`
4. Looping from beginning to end when deleting individual rows will cause complications (given their indexes *[indices(?)]* change) - or to better word myself - it is a valid practice, but you should know what you're doing with the indexes. In your case it seems much easier to them them in the LIFO order.
5. Last but not least, you're unnecessarily complicating your code with certain declarations (not an error so to say, but something to be improved upon)

With all the considered, your code should look something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub remove_empty_rows()
Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Your Sheet Name")
Dim lr as Long
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim i as Long
For i = lr to 1 Step -1
   If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 1)) Then
      ws.Rows(i).Delete
   End If
Next i

End Sub
```

In general, without meaning to sound condescending, it looks like you have some learning gaps in your coding practice. I'd refer properly reading some documentation or tutorial first, before actually doing coding like this yourself.

Comment: `Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete` should be `ws.Rows(i).Delete` I think, because `Rows(i)` is already the entire row. Also `i` should declare as `Dim i As Long`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I think both should work, but yes, technically `.EntireRow` is excessive here. As to the `i` declaration, my code didn't have `Option Explicit` so it wouldn't cause a hassle, but I guess it is a good practice to get to using, given OP seems fairly new to VBA anyways. Edited accordingly, thanks for the revision.

Comment: No worries, didn't say it won't work, just a improvement ;)  But `Rows(i).Delete` should really specify the worksheet `ws.Rows(i).Delete` (as I commented) to avoid any odd behavior.

Comment: Also, it's best practice to loop backwards when deleting rows otherwise you may skip over some rows by mistake

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account that `A17` cell is a header, you could use `AutoFilter` instead of iterating over cells:

```
Sub FastDeleteMethod()
    Dim rng As Range, rngFiltered As Range
    Set rng = Range("A17:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=0, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngFiltered = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If Err = 0 Then rngFiltered.EntireRow.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Sub
```